# suddenly right click selection does not work

Tags: selection-tools

suddenly i cannot select anymore with right click (or example objects in object mode or faces in edit mode). I was doing this tutorial and they asked me to change a few things in user preferences and now i cannot select anything.

Answer (score 3):

go back to the user preferences, go to input and change select with: to right

[image]

Comment: select is set to right click. but still i cannot select anything

Comment: maybe you should look in the outliner and look at the arrows (next to the eye) of a mesh. If this is off you have to click on them so you can select the objects

Comment: what is the outliner ?

Comment: @Jan Scherders this is the outliner: http://online.ts2009.com/mediaWiki/images/a/a2/Blender_Simple_Animation_Tute-Outliner_window.jpg

Comment: i have just opened a new file. still the same. probably i am doing something  very stupid thing wrong

Comment: for you information: I am in blender 2.75

Comment: maybe you should load the factory settings

Comment: go to file --> load factory settings

Comment: i did that and still the same

Comment: hmm, maybe a new mouse?

Comment: I did restore my mac system with an earlier version ...could that be the explanation ?

Comment: yes, but i don't authorisation. my reputation is not high enough

Comment: problem is solved. I restored my mac system and now i find that the system preferences of my mouse are suddenly the standard preferences. that is why right click suddenly does not work anymore. I made the association because gladys asked wether i had a new mouse

Answer (score 3):

Eventually you may try to ***Load Factory Settings***. It'll restore your RMB click functionality, but also change all your current settings. Make sure to save your work first though.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My RMB on a mac stopped working for selecting, too.

Changing from ortho to perspective view (View:Persp/Ortho) and back again seems to fix the problem.

Loading factory settings didn't help. I could select from the outliner, but not with a RMB click on objects. It would work on a new document, but not my saved document though. This happened several times. Anyone else experience this issue?

Comment: [Ask a new question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) please, if you think this one is related then include a link to this one as well. Answer box is only for answers to the question, not new question.

Answer (score 0):

Hit similar issue and since this page is first on Google - leaving answer.

Problem:
- MacOs
- Blender 2.79
- Right button works in outliner, but NOT 3D view

Solution:
- change camera near clip distance to some low value and then back

Suddenly right click started to work as usual